# sql query integer in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database, that I can not modify, which contains in a table1 in a varchar(255) field1, an 32 bit integer value.

I am interested in the last ten, or such, records of said table from which the integer is smaller than a given parameter value.

Running the next sql statement almost works:

```
echo 'select field1 from table1 where field1 < 123456 order by field1;'|mysql
```

The problem is that field1 contains values like

```
123450
123453
```

which answer to the selection, but also values like

```
12344
12345
```

which also meet the criteria, because of the sort order and method used (sort with string?).

The problem of course is the lack of leading zero's, which I can not help.

What is the best way of solving this in a pure sql query way? Because of time constraints in the final solution, I prefer a single query per parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value by treating it as numeric.  Here is a simple way:

```
select field1
from table1
where field1 + 0 < 123456
order by field1 + 0;
```

The `+ 0` does "silent conversion".  If the string is not a number, then it returns 0.  The conversion only applies to leading digits in the string.

In general, it is best to use the correct type.  If the field contains non-numeric values, you might want:

```
where field1 + 0 < 123456 and
      field1 + 0 > 0
```

Comment: Will external type casting work  like ` SELECT CONVERT('test', CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
SELECT CAST('test' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);`

Comment: @RanadipDutta . . . I believe that will return an error if the string contains non-digits.

Comment: Yes right. But I must say that silent conversion is great